# How to establish connection after connection error for RabbitMQ with a SpringBoot app

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, rabbitmq, connection, amqp

After redeploying my SpringBoot application into a TomcatServer 9 I got some strange exception:

> MyApplication: 2021-05-17 09:54:39,306 ERROR [AMQP Connection
> host:port]

o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory:1576 - Channel shutdown: connection error
Since then I cannot get any messages from RabbitMQ.

If I restart my app, then there is no exception.

Do I need to change something in my SpringBoot app to reconnect automatically after these errors?

Or what did I miss?

This is my SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory setup:

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory poxStatusFeedbackInterceptContainerFactory(final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                                                                                       final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void initializeContainer(SimpleMessageListenerContainer instance, RabbitListenerEndpoint endpoint) {
            instance.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(new MyPostProcessor()); // this does some prevalidation of messages
            super.initializeContainer(instance, endpoint);
        }
    };
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
}
```

And this is the application.yml setup:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: .......
    port: ....
    virtual-host: myhost
    username: sa
    password: sa
    listener:
      simple:
        retry:
          enabled: true
          initial-interval: 3s
          max-interval: 10s
          multiplier: 2
          max-attempts: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem:

```
((CachingConnectionFactory) connectionFactory).setRequestedHeartBeat(60);
```

Found here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html